# Categorizing timestamp into Morning, Afternoon, Evening

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a Hive table like so:

```
create table my_table
(
my_timestamp String
)
```

my_timestamp is of the format  `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. I need to categorize this into the following:

- Early Morning: Between 6:01AM to 9:00AM
- Morning: 9:01 to 12:00PM
- Afternoon: 12:01 to 3:00PM
- Evening: 3:01PM to 6:00PM
- Night 6:01PM to 05:59AM.

One option is to convert my_timestamp to a `unix_timestamp()`, create another `unix_timestamp()` for Early Morning, Morning etc, and then subtract the 2 `unix_timestamps()` to categorize it.

I was wondering if anyone could think of an easier way to do this. Any help appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even if I 've not used Hive, I guess I would just need the `int hour(string date)` function from here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions and the corresponding `minute()` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
select    
case floor(hour(my_timestamp) / 3)
when 2 then 'Early Morning'
when 3 then 'Morning'
when 4 then 'Afternoon'
when 5 then 'Evening'
else 'Night'
done
from my_table
```